# Dask read all hdf files over subdirs

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have a file structure that is as follows:

```
\parentdir
 -\subdirs
   -\hdf_file.hdf
```

where the subdirs are in the thousands, but the hdf_file.hdf has the same name in each subdirectory. The problem is that not every subdir has a hdf_file.hdf. I tried reading them all in with dask as follows:

```
all_data=dd.read_hdf('/path/to/parentdir/*/hdf_file.hdf','/data')
```

Which works until the first folder that doesn't have an hdf_file.hdf. How can I circumvent this problem?